# Algebraic Data Types using Nat (singleton library)

Tags: haskell, gadt, singleton-type

I've been trying to declare an Algebraic Data Type to operate at the level of types using the singletons library. I can do it without much trouble if I don't use in the constructors `Nat`, `Symbol`, `Integer` or `String`. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType           #-}

import           Data.Singletons
import           Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons [d|
  data Dim where
    NS :: Dim -- no size
    D  :: Bool -> Dim
   deriving (Eq, Show)
  |])

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let b = case toSing (D True) of
            (SomeSing d) -> show $ fromSing d
  putStrLn b
```

But it fails if I change `Bool` for either `Nat` or `Integer`.

How can I define an Algebraic Data Type to work with constructors that take `Nat` or `Integer` at the type level?

Answer (score 1):

From the README I gather that this is not possible directly because of the special status of `Nat`, but it also links to a possible workaround (see the last comment in the Github issue below): wrap Nat in some datatypes that singletons can handle.

https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/issues/76